# add two or more email in order confirmation email in magento 2

Tags: magento2

i am working on the order section now i am want to add one or more email to received a order email in magento 2.1.5 version.  i am try to add code on the file .
vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ QuoteManagement.php

475 $order->setCustomerEmail($quote->getCustomerEmail());

```
        $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $connection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION');
       $result1 = $connection->fetchAll(" SELECT *
        FROM  `mg1_customer_entity_varchar` WHERE  `entity_id` = '$suser_id' "); 

       $customemail = $result1[0]['value']; 

    $order->setCustomerEmail($customemail ,$quote->getCustomerEmail());
    $order->setCustomerFirstname($quote->getCustomerFirstname());
    $order->setCustomerMiddlename($quote->getCustomerMiddlename());
    $order->setCustomerLastname($quote->getCustomerLastname());
```

with is code i am getting objectManager |magento\frmework\app\objectManager error .

In addition 
when i am add emailaddress in  $order->setCustomerEmail("test@gmail.com" ,$quote->getCustomerEmail()); like code then i will send email only first email address it will not pick the second email address parameter can anyone help me to resolved it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in admin under,

store->configuration->sales->sales emails->order.

In Send Order Email Copy To input field insert multiple email id's with comma separated and order email will also sent to these emails also.

Comment: Thanks for response but my concerns is related to the pragmatically i mean in code because i want to add a dynamic email which i want to get from my custom module database table.  like in this file there     (vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ QuoteManagement.php)  there have a option but i am not able to fixed the error. please help me..